# Is it good practice to create AMQP queues manually or programmatically?

Tags: rabbitmq, message-queue, amqp

I'm in the process of implementing various remote methods/RPCs on the top of AMQP (RabbitMQ in particular). When a worker (or a client) comes online, it could, in theory, declare (create) a queue on the exchange. The other approach is to just start using a queue and assume that it already exists on the exchange.

Which approach is more common? Creating queues manually has a higher administrative cost, maybe; however, it can result in a more consistent environment if we decouple queue management from queue usage.

Answer (score 1):

It depends what is the requirement. If you have a fixed number of queues and dont need it to be generated dynamically, then go for manual. Example : It is a integration application and I know I have 3 consumers A,B,C then I will manually create 3 queues. Another example in a chat application for every logged in user I want to create a queue, in that case queues should be created programatically. And in case manual creation, you have more control to implement permissions and ACLs.

Comment: I agree with Manmay. "it depends" is a good answer... most of the time, I would say your application code should define the queues. but there are times when it is easier for me to just go in and create the queue myself. especially when i am just prototyping things and not yet sure if it is what i want

Answer (score 0):

Meanwhile I found out that according to RabbitMQ applications should take care of managing the queues they use.

Comment: Is there a citation that can be added for this?